# Local file protocol for java.net.URL

Tags: java, file, url, file-uri

What's the protocol for local files using URL? I've downloaded a file using Java and I need to know how to access it, not using File, but using URL.

Answer (score 37):

### Unix

```
file://localhost/<path>
file:///<path>
```

### Windows

```
file://localhost/<drive>|/<path>
file:///<drive>|/<path>
file://localhost/<drive>:/<path>
file:///<drive>:/<path>
```

For more information see the [related Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_url).

Answer (score 8):

You may use `file:///` and file path. For e.g. `file:///c:/temp.txt`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using that now.