# Unable to install custom connector in mule

Tags: maven, mule, mule-studio

I have developed the custom connector using the tutorial given [Hello-Connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Installing+and+Testing+Your+Connector)

The build was successful after running the maven command from the console. When I  try to install the connector in my mule studio, it is not able to locate it at the specified path.[image]

The structure of the UpdateSite.zip folder is [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/8406282/387927 shouldn't the path start with:

```
file:///D:/Mule/Examples/...
```

?

Comment: I tried to specify the path as file:///D:/Mule/Examples/abc/hello-connector/target/UpdateSite.zip but the mule studio automatically converts it back to file:/D:/Mule/Examples/abc/hello-connector/target/UpdateSite.zip.
Since its the first time I am developing the custom connector, could you let me know as per the attached screenshot if the structure of the UpdateSite folder is correct, all required files are present?

Comment: DevKit generates valid UpdateSite.zip: the content of yours looks right. The issue is that Studio can't locate the update site, not with its content. Maybe this doesn't work on Windows? I know it works on Linux and OS X for sure.