# Suddenly unable to install new version of custom connector in Studio

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

This is not covered by [Unable to install custom connector in mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863570) ....

I have been always been able to update Studio with the new versions of the custom connector using simple workflow of

1. Right-click on the connector project and select AnyPoint Connector -> Install or Update
2. Restart Studio

But, suddenly updates are not occurring. I've expanded to try

1. Clean connector project
2. Build connector project
3. AnyPoint Connector -> Install or Update
4. Restart Studio
5. Clean target project
6. Build target project

The changes are still not applied

I have also tried uninstalling the connector (and restarting Studio), but the target project still seems to find it even while the plug-ins-installed panel does not show it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new workspace and imported the target project and the connector project into it. That did not help, but it did rule out Studio per se.

So I looked in the local maven repo and realized I had not updated by target project pom to use the newer SNAPSHOT version of the connector project.

Solved.