# Externalize logback config on Windows

Tags: slf4j, logback

I know that I can externalize my logback.xml with the -D param `-Dlogback.configurationFile=...` (See [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty)).

I also know, that under Unix I have to do something like `file://localhost/users/.../logback.xml` to address an absolute file path.

But how do I do it on Windows? My absolute Path is something like `G:my\logbakc\config\logback.xml`

I use logback in combination with Slf4j and SpringBoot 1.2.2.RELEASE.

Comment: This should be the correct approach for referencing file paths on Windows. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8406282/1990536

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to configure loggers levels in your externalized `logback.xml`, you could also do it in your `application.[properties|yml]` spring-boot configuration file:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

Indeed, the application configuration file's externalization feature is already integrated in spring-boot (see documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)).

See [spring-boot's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) about this topic.

Comment: It's nice to know that I can configure the logging level with the properties. But that is not exactly what I want.
I want to use this to run the application on the server and that the System Administrators can put a logbackfile somewhere on the filesystem and edit it. Not only the logging level, but also the paths to the logfile or even the appenders.

Comment: Ok, I understand. In this case, I don't have the answer to your question, sorry :-/