# Referring to a local file using java.net.URL: MalformedURLException

Tags: java, url, intellij-idea

I'm trying to referring to a local file using java.net.URL, the code is as follows:

```
import java.net.URL;
public class Main
{
    URL grammarURL = new URL("file://localhost/home/me/openccg/ccg-format-grammars/tinytiny/tinytiny-grammar.xml");
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

But my IDE tells me that there is a "MalformedURLException" in the URL line. I followed instructions from [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406025/local-file-protocol-for-java-net-url) but it doesn't work.

Comment: you have to `catch` the exception, even if it doesn't occur. This is called a "checked exception".

Comment: @Zircon Thanks~ Problem solved!